# How to deal with big files in Git?

Tags: git, maven, soapui

We have a Maven project that is a testing suite, composed of some relatively big xml files (+30mb and one file of 1gb), which are actually SoapUI projects.

The usual development cycle is that the testers are going to modify these files and add/or add new ones.

How do we should versionate these kind of projects? If we compress the files we won't have history but if we don't compress then the project becomes very unhandy to deal with.

Comment: Usually you use git lfs for large files ...I made the experience that the overhead of using lfs is usually not worth the effort just store it...and what are the real problem with that files?

Comment: I would like to understand where these very large files come from. I guess you didn't write them manually? So, instead of versioning these files, could you version the procedure that generates them?

Comment: @JFMeier no, they are not generated.

Comment: So how did you write 1gb by hand?

Comment: @JFMeier I'm not sure how it was created, but most probably by copy&paste. But yes, I also think that particular file could be possible to be generated. But in any case, there are other big files that for sure are hand-crafted. The thing is that the main goal is to optimize the project how it is now. We all know how legacy code is painful...

Comment: Maybe you could split the files into many separate files. Then the burden for git to deal with the changes would be smaller.

Comment: Really a single file 1 GiB size? This file/approach should be reconsidered. Who really knows what inside that file? Is that file handled/created with/by a tool?

Comment: I got the same problem... a dataset of xml, svg, 3d files... 2.5gb total... about 10,000 files, not sure what the biggest is yet... yes, all written by hand using other composer technical software. Critical dataset that can't be changed without official order... we want to track it like git, its basically code in xml form, but size limits are a concern with github, and .git folder itself might get big. Looking for common solution, not sure lfs is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GIT [large file storage.](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

(On PC)

- Install GIT.
- Install GIT-LFS
- Open Bash ( that comes with GIT).
- Go to your repository folder. (where the .git folder is).
- type "git lfs install" (that'll setup LFS).
- type "git lfs track "*.psd" (or whatever file type/extension you want to add to the LFS).
- add the new file ".gitattributes" to your repository.

Note, as per [doc](https://git-lfs.github.com/) :
"Note that defining the file types Git LFS should track will not, by itself, convert any pre-existing files to Git LFS, such as files on other branches or in your prior commit history. To do that, use the git lfs migrate[1](https://git-lfs.github.com/) command, which has a range of options designed to suit various potential use cases."

Also, see documentation.

Comment: Could you explain more on how this works? Does this require extra infrastructure?

Comment: I'm using it, but I did not implement it; I will try setting it up on my home PC.